# my below query is very slow please tell me what is the reason

Tags: sql

```
SELECT cm.course_id, xu.full_path, xu.file_name, xu.file_id, xu.virtual_server
FROM cms_doc.xyf_urls xu
LEFT JOIN bb_bb60.course_main cm ON xu.full_path LIKE '/courses/' ||
cm.course_id OR xu.full_path LIKE '/courses/' || cm.course_id || '%'
WHERE xu.full_path NOT LIKE '/orgs%'
AND xu.full_path NOT LIKE '/institution%'
AND xu.full_path NOT LIKE '/library%'
AND xu.full_path NOT LIKE '/internal%'
AND xu.full_path NOT LIKE '/user%'
ORDER BY cm.course_id
```

Comment: That's not Objective-C, that's SQL.

Comment: First, if you don't already know, figure out how to get an explain plan of the query ...

Comment: Do you have an index on full_path field?

Answer (score 2):

It's slow because all of the all the `LIKE`s, particularly as part of the `JOIN`.

Comment: and even more so the NOT LIKEs.

Comment: yes but I guess the real slowness is due to the  `OR` and partially the `LIKE` in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Agree. That's one I haven't seen before. I'll put it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that there is an index on `xu.full_path`.

Second, one of the two `OR` conditions seems redundant. Try using this:

```
SELECT cm.course_id, xu.full_path, xu.file_name, xu.file_id, xu.virtual_server
FROM cms_doc.xyf_urls xu
  LEFT JOIN bb_bb60.course_main cm
    ON xu.full_path LIKE '/courses/' || cm.course_id || '%'
WHERE xu.full_path NOT LIKE '/orgs%'
  AND xu.full_path NOT LIKE '/institution%'
  AND xu.full_path NOT LIKE '/library%'
  AND xu.full_path NOT LIKE '/internal%'
  AND xu.full_path NOT LIKE '/user%'
ORDER BY cm.course_id
```